# Why does optimizing javascript give me errors using Drupal?

Tags: javascript, drupal-6

When I enabled "Optimize JavaScript files" on admin/settings/performance, I get the following errors on my page:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } /public/js/a64b50c1e33d2f569fa02e6d2f2fcc31.js:3450
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined ?pid=1118045709:33
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ?pid=1118045709:38
Uncaught ReferenceError: filterlist is not defined ?pid=1118045709:193
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined ?pid=1118045709:276
```

When I disabled "Optimize JavaScript files", the page works as expected and I get no errors.

Comment: Do you know exactly how this "optimization" is being done?

Comment: Looks like here "optimize" means "concat -> compress", which does not take care about how exactly dependencies need to be managed. What's that tool you're using ?

Comment: It's on drupal's admin/settings/performance page. This is what it says "Bandwidth optimizations
Drupal can automatically optimize external resources like CSS and JavaScript, which can reduce both the size and number of requests made to your website. CSS files can be aggregated and compressed into a single file, while JavaScript files are aggregated (but not compressed). These optional optimizations may reduce server load, bandwidth requirements, and page loading times.
These options are disabled if you have not set up your files directory, or if your download method is set to private."

Comment: Does drupal take care of the order the files are being linked?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - yes

Comment: Maybe if you'll play with order of script elements in your pages, like moving all jQuery plugins under the jQuery script itself, etc. it could help with this error. 
If you do not want to just get away from it, but make your JS better, you can check some more complex dependency managers, like [require.js](http://requirejs.org)

Comment: I can't... this is something that drupal does.

Comment: This might be a cache problem. Try to flush the cache and see what happens!

Comment: I tried that and still getting the same problems

Answer (score 0):

All I did was clean up the javascript file - formatting things correctly and then flushed the cache and it works now.